# Dubai non-practising muslim

Tags: legal, religion

My husband is half Irish half Iraqi, and an Irish passport holder. Our marriage certificate says he is Muslim. I am Christian but in reality, we are neither and have no religious beliefs at all.

If we move to Dubai for work, will he be considered a Muslim due to his nationality, name, marriage certificate, etc?

Will he be able to do an expat non-Muslim will, or will he have to do Shariah law will? We have kids and have a will made in our home country and understand we should do the same in Dubai.

Will life be stricter if they consider him a Muslim than if they thought we were Christians?

Comment: I assume you are female, is that correct?

Comment: I am unsure about the will but Dubai is much more liberal when compared with say, Saudi. From my experience, they do not enforce separate strict rules on Muslims in Dubai. However, please refrain from eating in front of Muslims during Ramzan or consuming liquor in public. But these rules are applicable to everyone. Also, just don't mention that you are not a practicing Muslim publicly. I do not know anyone who has done so and without precedent, I can't say if that's a fair thing to say or not.